# Confidence Interval for Training data

Tags: r, model, confidence-interval

I am building a time series model in R with training data and predicting the future values.

```
fit_arima   <- auto.arima(train.ts, xreg=xreg.vars.train)
```

I get the CI for the predicted data using the model that I developed with training data.

```
fcast_arima <- forecast(fit_arima, xreg = xreg.vars.test, h= nrow(test.data), level=95)

         Point Forecast    Lo 95    Hi 95
Apr 2015       2.000000 1.396790 2.603210
May 2015       2.000000 1.396790 2.603210
Jun 2015       2.397746 1.794537 3.000956
Jul 2015       2.000000 1.396790 2.603210
Aug 2015       2.397746 1.794537 3.000956
Sep 2015       2.000000 1.396790 2.603210
Oct 2015       2.000000 1.396790 2.603210
Nov 2015       2.397746 1.794537 3.000956
Dec 2015       2.795493 2.192283 3.398702
```

But I am looking for a way to get CI for training data as well. Can someone help to find the way to do?

Thanks,
Kaly

Comment: `forecast.Arima` provides prediction intervals.  Are you looking for the prediction intervals with your training data?   `forecast(fit_arima, xreg = xreg.vars.train)`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.  The code `forecast(fit_arima, xreg = xreg.vars.train)` gives me the fit and CI for future data points not for the  actual training data. For example, if I have training data from JAN-12 until AUG-14, the above code gives me the fit and CI from SEP-14 not from JAN-12.